# Safe way to prevent sql injection with mybatis

Tags: mybatis

I am using '$' notation in mybatis query:

```
<select id="queryOrgs" resultMap="orgLiteMap" parameterType="gov.cbrc.gzbanking.data.QueryRequest" >
        select id, name from sys_orgs
        <if test="filter != null">where id like #{filter, jdbcType=INTEGER} or name like #{filter, jdbcType=INTEGER}</if>
        <if test="order != null">order by ${order}</if>
        limit #{offset, jdbcType=INTEGER},#{fetch, jdbcType=INTEGER}
     </select>
```

the order parameter can be something like "id desc", do I need to worry about sql injection here? We know that mybatis uses `PreparedStatement`, if mybatis call `PreparedStatement#executeQuery()` against "select" statement, or the jdbc driver implementation does't allow multiple statements in one call, then sql injection is impossible, am I right?

If that is possible for sql injection in my case, what's the verified way to prevent it ?

------------------------ **edit** -----------------------

Is that enough to check `order` parameter has a sql delimiter?

Answer (score 3):

If `order` comes directly from the user, you can get into trouble. **You should never trust user input**.

To respond to your questions:

- If you don't allow multiple queries you will get an exception if you try running more than one, yes;
- checking for an SQL delimiter might be enough, might not;

Using `${}` exposes you to SQL injection if you send the user input unchanged to the SQL. The above two methods are fragile:

- you can easily forget to configure the connection or a colleague of yours might turn it on because he/she needs to execute multiple queries in one statement and they were not aware about this particular statement
- hackers might be smarter than checks you have in place (e.g have you considered testing for `\u003B` too? What else might an attacker attempt?).

Always perform your own escapes and checks and send a value you control, not something received from the user. Have all the correct values in your code and send that instead. It's then just a matter of determining which one the user wanted and fallback to a default if you can't determine it, something like:

```
String userChoice = order.toLowerCase();
String safeOrder = null;

if ("id desc".equals(userChoice)) {
    safeOrder = "id desc";
} else if ("id asc".equals(userChoice)) {
    safeOrder = "id asc";
....
....
} else if ("name desc".equals(userChoice)) {
    safeOrder = "name desc";
} else {
    // if no clean match then maybe user tried something fishy... 
    // ... go with some default 
    safeOrder = "id desc"; // or null or whatever you like...
}
```

then in your mapping you do:

```
<if test="safeOrder != null">order by ${safeOrder}</if>
```

Comment: sorry replay late. I am checking 'order' parameter using regex '(?i)^\\w+\\s+(desc)?(asc)?$' now.

Answer (score 3):

See https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html. section 'String Substitution' for offical comment on that.

> It's not safe to accept input from a user and supply it to a statement
>   unmodified in this way. This leads to potential SQL Injection attacks
>   and therefore you should either disallow user input in these fields,
>   or always perform your own escapes and checks.

Comment: Differences between $ and # usage is pretty well explained here: https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-mybatis

Comment: Link in previous comment was no longer good, web archive version: http://web.archive.org/web/20200812181807/https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-mybatis

Answer (score 0):

My answer, mybatis sql template may be a good choose. FYI:

```
 <sql id="orderTypeSql">
    <trim prefix=" ">
        <if test="'desc'.equalsIgnoreCase(orderType)">desc</if>
    </trim>
</sql>
<sql id="orderColumnSql">
    <trim prefix="order by " suffix="" >
        <choose>
            <when test="orderColumn==null or orderColumn==''"></when>
            <when test="orderColumn=='id'">
                id<include refid="orderTypeSql"/>
            </when>
            <when test="orderColumn=='name'">
                `name`<include refid="orderTypeSql"/>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </trim>
</sql>
<select id="testOrderBy" resultType="User">
    select
    id,
    `name`
    from t_user
    <include refid="orderColumnSql"/>
    limit 0, 10
</select>
```